# Error validating formula for calculated column

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to make up a calculated column that evaluates an existing column with a CASE statement. The following code works fine:

```
CASE 
  WHEN Technician_Production_date IS NULL THEN 1 
  WHEN Technician_Production_date IS NOT NULL AND Technician_Review_Date IS NULL THEN 2 
  WHEN Technician_Production_date IS NOT NULL AND Technician_review_Date IS NOT NULL AND 
  Chemist_Review_Date IS NULL THEN 3 
  ELSE 4 
END
```

When i try to do the same statement but assign an existing column as a VARCHAR value instead as below, i get the error: "Error validating formula for (column_name)". Here is the code im trying to run:

```
CASE 
  WHEN Technician_Production_date IS NULL THEN CAST(Responsible_Technician_Review AS varchar) 
  WHEN (Technician_Production_date IS NOT NULL AND Technician_Review_Date IS NULL) THEN 
  CAST(Responsible_Chemist_Review AS varchar) 
  WHEN (Technician_Production_date IS NOT NULL AND Technician_review_Date IS NOT NULL AND 
  Chemist_Review_Date IS NULL)  THEN CAST(Responsible_Chemist_Approval AS varchar) 
  ELSE "Finished") 
END
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: *"Error validating formula for (column_name)"* Isn't a SQL Server error; how are you trying to do this? Are you using the designer? If so, I strongly suggest you don't; learn the SQL to add a computed column (which is part of `ALTER TABLE`). Also have a read of [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: `ELSE "Finished"`: use correct quotes: `ELSE 'Finished'`

Comment: Your second and third WHEN conditions are a subset of the first - they are redundant. It may be you have them backwards but it currently won't do what you think it does.